# What is the alternative in javascript to input type file to upload images from client to server?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a more flexible way in JavaScript (not JQ or added libraries)
to do the same as you can see below in HTML:

```
<form action="images.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I need that in JavaScript because in JavaScript I can issue also additional params in post message body. 
I want to do something that will remind the following (partially pseudo code):

HTML:

```
<a onclick=addImage()> Add your photo </a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addImage(){

var image = <functionality to open file browser to choose image to send>

var xmlhttp;



if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
       //page.reload();
    }
}


   xmlhttp.open("POST",urlPHP + "images.php",true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.send(image);


}
```

Comment: `// code for IE6, IE5` Nooooooooooooooooo!

Comment: *"I need that in JavaScript because in JavaScript I can issue also additional params in post message body."* You can just do that with fields in the form.

Comment: Yes, also, please stop supporting IE6 and older!

Comment: Have a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/.

Comment: Why to stop using IE5, IE6 and older?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If that is possible then how can I add a variable to post message in POST inside html form?

Comment: `<input type='hidden' name='my_variable' value='my_value'>`

Comment: @Canttouchit: The only reasons for supporting IE6 are: Either 1. You have a client specifically requiring you to, or 2. You are creating a web page/application for use in China, where IE6 (mostly in the form of ISP-specific branded browsers using an embedded IE6 control) still accounts for 24% of the user base. (With just a mention of Taiwan at 3.5% and India at 2.8%.) Essentially everywhere else, IE6 (and IE7) are dead. Finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of demos out there that provide you with the source:

Drag And Drop example: http://html5demos.com/file-api

Form Example: http://www.script-tutorials.com/pure-html5-file-upload/

Note that for older browsers you still have to use something other than JS.